# Why textarea and input text with same font-size, line-height, padding and height are vertically aligned differently?

Tags: html, css, input, textarea, vertical-alignment

[image]

**QUESTION 1:**

Why do the following `textarea` and text `input` have **different vertical text alignment** if they both have the same `font-size`, `line-height`, `height`, `padding` ?

**QUESTION 1.1**

How can I make the `textarea` have the same vertical alignment as the `input` ?

```css
.myTextarea {
  display: block;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 21px;
  height: 32px;
  padding: 2px 5px;

  resize: none;
}

.myInput {
  display: block;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 21px;
  height: 32px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}

.myDiv {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="myDiv">Textarea</div>
  <textarea class="myTextarea" rows="1">12345</textarea>
  <div class="myDiv">Input</div>
  <input class="myInput" type="text" value="12345"/>
</div>
```

Comment: worth to note that textarea is for multiline text while input is for one line

Comment: I agree. That's probably the cause of the difference. But still I would like to know how to style them the same when they both have only 1 line. Thanks!

Comment: remove the height value and start increasing the line-height until for example 34px (since it's one line, there is no issue to have a big line-height)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Textareas are for multiline texts while inputs are made for single line.

That's why line height won't have effect on input as it's considered to be equal to the input's height.

You can remove line height on your input since it has no effect on it.

Beside you should have the same line height as height for your textarea to reproduce the same effect than the input.

```css
.myTextarea {
  display: block;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  padding: 2px 5px;

  resize: none;
}

.myInput {
  display: block;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 32px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}

.myDiv {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="myDiv">Textarea</div>
  <textarea class="myTextarea" rows="1">12345</textarea>
  <div class="myDiv">Input</div>
  <input class="myInput" type="text" value="12345"/>
</div>
```

Comment: that does not answer the OP question, WHY

Comment: @serge does it now?